# Android : Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to edit `SharedPreferences` of one app through another app, my code goes like this

```
try {
Context plutoContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext("me.test",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences plutoPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(plutoContext);
Editor plutoPrefEditor = plutoPreferences.edit();
plutoPrefEditor.putString("country", "India");
plutoPrefEditor.commit();
}
```

I am getting an error

`E/SharedPreferencesImpl(  304): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file /data/data/me.test/shared_prefs/me.test_preferences.xml`

where `me.test` is my another project
in me.test proj I can edit and retrieve `SharedPreferences` with no pain

I am testing it on Nexus S android 4.0.4 (Samsung), can any one help me

Comment: Your "me.test" project has created the SharedPreferences with `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`?

Comment: @ WarrenFaith, thanks for comment. I dont know how to create `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` with, I just created normal

Comment: Could you also write the kind of exception?

Comment: @ teoREtik, thanks for comment. its not crashing but when I see log I got the result as I mentioned in question

Comment: I'm having the same problem with preferenceActivity on Android Studio, and  testing it on LG-D855.
When I run the app and close it by *Back* button everything works, but when I close it completely everything is gone, and there is this error in logcat:
**Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file**

Comment: I don't know that this is logical or not, but after clearing application data (_on application information_) everything went back to normal. I think installing on and on the application for testing purposes made this problem, thanks BTW.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I have the same problem with you, and I solved it with the above solution.

Comment: are you sure, add permissions to access shared prefs?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a different package name in this app. That will create the preferences in a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, (it's not related with the question, but any way) you wrongly use `createPackageContext()` method. You pass there `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` flag which value is **2** and equals to `CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY` flag, so this would be incorrectly interpreted by logic, IMHO.

Comment: I dont know much about IMHO. my basic thing is to edit shared preferences of one app from another app

Comment: So you should create `SharedPreferences` in application which owns it with `getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)` using `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` mode as @WarrenFaith said.

Comment: MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE  is deprecated now

Answer (score 1):

Issue - "Android : Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file" will come when you are already created default shared preference in project. 
So, one shared preference is exist and again, you are adding with same name default preference. 
Solution - Create only one default shared preference in app. If do you want to create more shared preference then create shared preference with some name.

Note - Only one default shared preference in one app.

Answer (score 0):

If your first app wants to create a SharedPreference that can be read by another app, make sure you create the SharedPreference with the correct mode. Take a look at the [getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) or the [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) class for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case rebooting Samsung device solved same issue.